# Is it possible to update arrays while they are in loops?

Tags: php

i was wondering if its possible to update array objects in loop

```
<?php
foreach($arrObj as $value)
{
    if(is_array($value))
    {
       $arrObj = $value; // the foreach array object should change and run new value
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: So, what actually happens when you run that code? Does it do what you expect?

Comment: share sample data for `$arrObj` ?

Comment: Exactly what @jh314 trying to say : https://eval.in/1044336

Comment: What am trying to say is this.
$arrayObj = array('php', 'java', array('UI', UX'), '.NET');

My question is that if the value is an array of array('UI', UX') can we now update $arrObj to be this new value of array('UI', UX') ?

Answer (score 0):

php will loop over a "view" of the top level elements of `$arrObj`, so changing `$arrObj` won't affect the loop. `$arrObj` itself will be assigned to `$value` as usual, so the last subarray will be saved into `$arrObj`.

Comment: What if I use array_push? Well I tried everything but didn't work

Answer (score 0):

you can't update the value of an array within a foreach loop on the same array but you can with other loops for,while and do...while :
see it yourself:

```
$array=[0,1,2,3,4,range(1,10)];
    for(;false!==key($array)&&NULL!==key($array);){
        $temp=[];
        list($k,$value)=each($array);
            print(str_repeat('#',32).'<br>');

        if(is_array($value))
            $array=$value;
        else
            print($value);
    }



$array=[0,1,2,3,4,range(1,10)];
    while(false!==key($array)&&NULL!==key($array)){
        $temp=[];
        list($k,$value)=each($array);
            print(str_repeat('#',32).'<br>');

        if(is_array($value))
            $array=$value;
        else
            print($value);
    }



$array=[0,1,2,3,4,range(1,10)];
    do{
        $temp=[];
        list($k,$value)=each($array);
            print(str_repeat('#',32).'<br>');

        if(is_array($value))
            $array=$value;
        else
            print($value);
    }   while(false!==key($array)&&NULL!==key($array));
```

these three loops achieve the same thing and the result printed is:

```
################################
0################################
1################################
2################################
3################################
4################################
################################
1################################
2################################
3################################
4################################
5################################
6################################
7################################
8################################
9################################
10
```

Comment: thanks, it doesn't but I found a way out. I appreciate your efforts

Comment: Can you please share with us your solution.It may help us too.

Comment: I used do while loop, what I was trying to achieve was to go through every levels of folder in my application and then get the files out. Using a do while loop, am able to get the first folder and if the result is a directory, scan it and get all files until results wasn't a directory.

Comment: This article is useful too http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php, see example 3

Comment: Ok. You must be more specific in your questions in the future. PHP have native directory Iterator to achieve this kind of purposes. You can browse the manual and find the rubric on Iterators. This may help you too.